# Photon matchmaking - Join or create a room using in Unity with an SQL lobby

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying to implement skill based matchmaking using Photon in Unity. It seems 
I got most of this code from the documentation and it works but not well. 
The problem is that you can't use JoinOrCreate() with the sql lobby type so my logic here is try and find a room, if it fails create one.

```
    void init()
    {
        _client = Game.Context.GetComponent<SocketConnectionManager>().client;
        joinRoom();
    }

    public void joinRoom()
    {
        TypedLobby sqlLobby = new TypedLobby("skillLobby", LobbyType.SqlLobby);
        string sqlLobbyFilter = "C0 BETWEEN 100 AND 200";
        _client.OpJoinRandomRoom(null, MatchMaker.MaxPlayers, MatchmakingMode.FillRoom, sqlLobby, sqlLobbyFilter);
    }

    public void createRoom()
    {
        RoomOptions o = new RoomOptions();
        o.MaxPlayers = MatchMaker.MaxPlayers;
        o.CustomRoomProperties = new Hashtable() { { "C0", Game.Me.getInt("trophies") } };
        o.CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = new string[] { "C0" }; // this makes "C0" available in the lobby
        TypedLobby sqlLobby = new TypedLobby("skillLobby", LobbyType.SqlLobby);
        _client.OpCreateRoom("", o, sqlLobby);
    }

    private void onEvent(EventData obj)
    {
        if (_client.CurrentRoom != null)
        {
            if (_client.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount >= _client.CurrentRoom.MaxPlayers)
            {
                // sweet I am good to go.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            createRoom();
        }
    }
```

The problem is this is pretty unreliable. Say two players try to find a game at the same time they will both search fail and then both create. Now I have two players sitting in empty rooms instead of playing each other.

Any ideas on a better system?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for choosing Photon!

First of all, there are few things that you should understand about Photon:

1. > you can't use JoinOrCreate() with the sql lobby type

   This is not correct.
   Where did you read such thing?
   Did you test this yourself? What did you test exactly?
2. `onEvent` (`LoadBalancingClient.OnEventAction`) callback cannot be used to be notified of a failed join random room operation. Instead, you should make use of the `LoadBalancingClient.OnOpResponseAction` callback, as follows:

   ```
   private void OnOpResponse(OperationResponse operationResponse) 
   {
       switch (operationResponse.Code) 
       {
           case OperationCode.JoinRandomGame:
               if (operationResponse.ReturnCode == ErrorCode.NoMatchFound) 
               {
                   createRoom();
               }
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
3. To detect a join event inside a room (local or remote player entered a room):

   ```
   private void onEvent(EventData eventData)
   {
       switch (eventData.Code)
       {
           case EventCode.Join:
               int actorNr = (int)eventData[ParameterCode.ActorNr];
               PhotonPlayer originatingPlayer = this.GetPlayerWithId(actorNr);
               if (originatingPlayer.IsLocal) 
               {
               }
               else 
               {
               }
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

To answer your question:

> Say two players try to find a game at the same time they will both
>   search fail and then both create.
>
> Any ideas on a better system?

No.
This issue happens only during the development phase where you use a few clients to run some tests. Once you have enough user base you won't notice this issue.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.

As for why I thought that you can't use sql filters for OpJoinOrCreateRoom I just don't see the option. When using the join random room I have a parameter to send that is the sql filers, no such options with JoinOrCreate. It would be great if I could use that instead then I wouldn't need the OnOpResponse callback all together. 
 
`_client.OpJoinRandomRoom(expectedCustomRoomProperties, expectedMaxPlayers, matchmakingMode, lobby, sqlLobbyFilter);`
`_client.OpJoinOrCreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions, lobby);`

Comment: You can OpJoinOrCreate rooms in SQL lobbies. I think you may be thinking that OpJoinOrCreate does a random join and creates if no match found, it's not the case, what it does is to try join a room given its name and creates it if it does not exist. There is no OpJoinRandomOrCreate.